# Variable no definida en lambda python?

Tags: python

¿Cómo resuelvo el error de variable no definida en lambda python?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas deben incluir el código, los datos de entrada y los errores como texto, así otros pueden replicar tu problema sin omitir posibles problemas que el transcribir desde una imagen va a ocultar.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Siempre es muuucho más fácil copiar y pegar texto que ponerse a incluir imágenes :) No es claro tampoco dónde ocurre la definición de las variables respecto del uso en el json que estás armando. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 0):

El error se produce porque a var1 no le estás pasando ningún valor entonces no se crea nunca.
Debe ser porque en alguna de las asignaciones anteriores perdés el valor.
Para solucionarlo anda imprimiendo los valores de slots DCI con print(slot) print(DCI) antes de asignarle valor a var1 y controla cuando no imprima nada.